# List of the macros used during a compilation

Tags: compiling

Is there a way to know the macros that were used by a compilation?

I would like to associate macros to packages such as to guess unused packages (my association can be approximative because I am not willing to have an exact guess).

Comment: Short answer: no. It makes no real sense, I'm afraid.

Comment: Realistically no.  You can add `\tracingmacros=1` at the beginning of your file, but that will give you _thousands_ of lines in the `.log` to parse through, so it's probably not worth the effort

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks. The parsing will be done by a script and then I would like to use IA tricks for the guessing.

Comment: @egreg No real sense? Why? The analysis will be done using scripts.

Comment: well try it: add \tracingmacros=1 and then check the log-file (but start with a small document).

Comment: Maybe easier would be to parse the `.tex` file and try to associate commands in the source to packages, without actually compiling. This fails for unused code that is in the document, for example in comments, or something unreachable in an if-statement etc, but those may be considered edge cases. Harder would be to actually make a list of which package defines which command, you could try parsing `.sty` files for `\def`, `\gdef`, `\edef`, `\xdef`, `\newcommand`, `\NewDocumentCommand` etc, but there may be dependencies to other files and commands with custom names (using `\csname` etc).

Comment: Try with `\tracingmacros=1{\bfseries x}\tracingmacros=0 ` and look in the log file for how many instances of `\bfseries` appear.

Comment: @egreg How do you count these instances? With some lines of `Bash` codes maybe. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to do that<sup>1</sup>, you can add `\tracingmacros=1` at the top of your document, then TeX will show you *every* macro expansion it does.  For example, with

```latex
\tracingmacros=1
\def\mycmd{hello \world}
\def\world{world!}
```

the `.log` will have:

```
\mycmd ->hello \world 

\world ->world!
```

so you can parse through that with a regex like `^\n.+?->` (it will fail with some longish complicated macros, but those are likely package internals, so for your need they should be of no interest).  You will need something else to extract the macro name from that match (usually delimiting by a space should work, so you can use the simper `^\n.+?\` , but that will give some false positives).

Mind you, that

```
\tracingmacros=1
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

produces 164000(!) lines of log.

  I wouldn't; I'd just try removing packages I think aren't used and see if the document builds correctly.

---

If you have a recent distribution (TeX Live 2021 at least) you can use the new `\tracingstacklevels` primitive:

```
\tracingmacros=1
\tracingstacklevels=1
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

then search for `^~~.+\n`: it should give a bit more reliable matches than with `\tracingmacros` only.

Comment: Just removing packages automatically is not feasible. I repeat that I will try to use this too verbose information to build a "tricky" way to guess a potential unuseful package. If I succeed in this funny project, I will put it on Github. Thanks for your complete answer.